# how to test redux-saga all effect using jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, redux-saga

```
function* mySaga() {
  const [customers, products] = yield all([
    call(fetchCustomers),
    call(fetchProducts)
  ])
}
```

I want to test all effect in jest but I get: `Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance`

my code is:

```
    const generator = mySaga()
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(all([
      call(fetchCustomers),
      call(fetchProducts)
    ]))
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just an issue happen on old `redux-saga`, your code will work on the latest version (v1.1.3 at the moment).

I created [a testing snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-saga-lycu9) for that, the test is working perfectly with  `redux-saga` version `1.1.3`. And we can reproduce this error if we downgrade the version to `0.16.2`.

So an version upgrade can fix this error. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to test all effect in jest but I get

To deal with an error, it is necessary to understand at first how function generator generally works, irrespective of redux-saga library. Every `yield` operation performs interrupting generator instance, and point with `yield` keyword in input/output entry.

So, right value of `yield` becomes `generator.next().value` result, and `generator.next(RESULT)` becomes left value of `yield` keyword. `Redux-saga` effects does not perform any special work, just makes special actions objects (https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/src/internal/io.js )

So, to solve original task, just pass value to `next()` generator function, which will be destructured in `const [customers, products] = yield` statement.

Comment: Can you provide the code, as it is unclear what 'value' we need to pass to next().

Comment: Same here, could you provide the snippet for your fixing. I made a test in codesandbox, and it's working out of box:  https://codesandbox.io/s/test-saga-lycu9. Not sure is it only an issue with specific Jest / Saga version.