# What's the best way to test redux-saga's `all` effect?

Tags: testing, redux-saga

I have a saga which currently has a `yield all(...)` and I'm trying to figure out how to test to see that I'm actually invoking `all()` with the correct functions. Here's a stripped-down version of what I'm working with:

```
function* start() {
  // I'd prefer not to start the status polling and the listening for
  // the cancellation until after the request has been submitted, but
  // I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that. So I'm just going
  // to listen for 'em all up front here until I'm smarter.
  yield all([
    waitForCreateRequest(),
    waitForPollStatus(),
    waitForCancelRequest(),
  ])
}

function* waitForCreateRequest() {
  while ( true ) {  
    try {
      const { payload } = yield take('CREATE_REQUEST')
      // ...
    } catch ( error ) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}

function* waitForPollStatus() {
  while ( true ) {  
    try {
      const { payload } = yield take('POLL_STATUS')
      // ...
    } catch ( error ) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}

function* waitForCancelRequest() {
  while ( true ) {  
    try {
      yield take('CANCEL_REQUEST')
      // ...
    } catch ( error ) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

The test that I wrote (using Mocha and `bdd-lazy-var`) goes something like this:

```
describe('MySaga', () => {
  describe('*start()', () => {
    subject(start())

    it('calls `all()` with the correct functions', () => {
      expect($subject.next().value).to.eql(all([
        waitForSubmitExportRequest(),
        waitForPollExportStatus(),
        waitForCancelExportRequest(),
      ]))
    })
  })
})
```

There is no output--it just hangs...and then I get a "JavaScript heap out of memory" error.

If I `console.log($subject.next().value)` instead:

```
describe('MySaga', () => {
  describe('*start()', () => {
    subject(start())

    it.only('foo', () => {
      console.log($subject.next().value)
    })
  })
})
```

This is what I get:

```
  MySaga
    *start()
{ '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
  ALL: 
   [ GeneratorFunctionPrototype { _invoke: [Function: invoke] },
     GeneratorFunctionPrototype { _invoke: [Function: invoke] },
     GeneratorFunctionPrototype { _invoke: [Function: invoke] } ] }
      ✓ foo
```

So I'm not sure what's going on here.

Countless Google searches didn't really turn up anything useful, and the closest SO post that I found ([how to test redux-saga all effect using jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401736/how-to-test-redux-saga-all-effect-using-jest)) was also unhelpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it a typo that your `start` function is not a generator function?

Anyway. Can you try to rewrite your `start` function like this:

```js
function* start() {
  yield all([
    call(waitForCreateRequest),
    call(waitForPollStatus),
    call(waitForCancelRequest),
  ])
}
```

Now your test could look like:

```js
it('calls `all()` with the correct functions', () => {
  expect($subject.next().value).to.eql(all([
    call(waitForSubmitExportRequest),
    call(waitForPollExportStatus),
    call(waitForCancelExportRequest),
  ]))
})
```

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thank you for pointing that out. Your suggestion works perfectly...thank you very much for bailing me out!